# Use data from one query in another?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    id, title, sort 
FROM 
    my_table 
WHERE 
    id = 1 AND 
    SELECT id, title 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE sort is > *sort from first select* 
LIMIT 1.
```

I'm trying to select a row from my table and then select another row based on the contents of the first select, can I do this? Or would it have to be two queries?

Basically, I'm trying to select row with id 1 and then get it's sort value, then find the row which has the next sort value above it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but retrieving it in one row:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table t1
    JOIN my_table t2 ON (t2.sort>t1.sort)
  WHERE t1.title="something you like"
  ORDER BY t2.sort DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest:

```
SELECT id, title, sort 
FROM my_table 
WHERE sort > (SELECT sort 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be

```
SELECT t1.id as Table1_id , t1.title as Table1_title ,
t1.sort as Table1_sort , t2.id as Table2_id, t2.title as Table2_title
FROM my_table t1 , my_table t2
WHERE t1.id = 1 AND  t2.sort > t1.sort
LIMIT 1.
```

This will produce your desired output.